# Required Win32 Application in Microsoft Intune

Tags: intune

I setup a Win32 Application in my Intune as Required, then one of my AAD Joined machines got the application installed. Later I explicitly uninstalled it and now Intune's app status displays an error for that application on that device:

*The application was not detected after installation completed successfully.
Couldn't detect app because it was manually updated after installation or uninstalled by the user.*

Doesn't matter what I do now in Intune I cannot get the application installed on that box again, that error is still displayed. Tried to "Sync" from both - the device as well as Intune - nothing helps in terms of that application's status in Intune.

Why the Required application is not automatically installed if a user uninstalled it? I find this contradicting with the definition of Required. How do I get the application installed back via Intune without asking the user to explicitly install it?

Comment: Is the application assigned to a user group or a device group? May there be conflicts between the groups assigned (please take a look at this in order to eliminate this possibility [Assign apps to groups with Microsoft Intune](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/apps-deploy). Also, you could try (if feasible) to remove the app assignment to the group, and then reassign the app to this group. This action can trigger the redeployment. Please inform if we have any update.